# Using a saved file directory

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

After getting a complete file directory structure from the file chooser, I would like to save the path in a `JButton` automatically, without manually feeding it (copying/pasting). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: This question is too general to be readily answered.   You need to add some specifics about what information you are seeking.  Not: I am trying to write a program, can someone do that for me?

Comment: I am using Netbeans to develop a simple Desktop Application. I want to be able to make a JButton which opens a JFileChooser. I then want to be able to use the absolute path of the chosen file in another method which reads the data file.

Answer (score 0):

read the JFileChooser javadocs, especially method getSelectedFile()

Comment: This answer would be better if it linked to the relevant method in the JavaDocs or quoted the relevant part of the method description (or both).